# How to read zarr files correctly from minio？

Tags: python, asynchronous, amazon-s3, bigdata, minio

I want to read a big `zarr` file from my minio(s3) server，however，after I changed three methods，they are all crashed：

```
import hydrodata.configs.config as conf

# Method 1
# https://pastebin.com/vkM1M3VV
zarr_path = await conf.FS.open_async('s3://datasets-origin/usgs_streamflow_nldas_hourly.zarr')
zds = xr.open_dataset(zarr_path, engine='zarr')
# Method 2
# https://pastebin.com/fKKECf3U
zarr_path = conf.FS.get_mapper('s3://datasets-origin/usgs_streamflow_nldas_hourly.zarr')
wrapped_store = zarr.storage.KVStore(zarr_path)
zds = xr.open_zarr(wrapped_store)
# Method 3
# AttributeError: __enter__
with conf.FS.open_async('s3://datasets-origin/usgs_streamflow_nldas_hourly.zarr') as zarr_path:
zds = xr.open_dataset(zarr_path)
```

And this is `conf.FS`:

```
FS = s3fs.S3FileSystem(
    client_kwargs={"endpoint_url": MINIO_PARAM["endpoint_url"]},
    key=MINIO_PARAM["key"],
    secret=MINIO_PARAM["secret"],
    use_ssl=False,
)
```

So how to solve their problem and let me get correct data?

———————————————————————————————————

This is my crash report in Method2：

```
name = 'xarray.core.daskmanager'
import_ = <function _gcd_import at 0x7fe2aabbb400>
 
>   ???
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray.core.daskmanager'
```

However I have run `pip install xarray[complete]` and `conda install -c conda-forge xarray dask netCDF4 bottleneck` before，so where's the problem?
This is my pip list: https://pastebin.com/BUbcNqtT

Comment: Method 2 is the only one here that should work: please show exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray.core.daskmanager'", however I have run `pip install xarray[complete]` before this.

Comment: Please paste your exception and full traceback into the question.
So this has nothing at all to do with s3fs. Please remove all that stuff, and ask about xarray-dask alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have redone this practice on another computer, at last I found this problem can't be reproduced.
Now I should close the problem.